# iOS - run app deep link from system settings

Tags: ios, swift

I see that some iOS apps allow running custom view controllers (or run app with deep link) from system settings. In example of LinkedIn app: Settings -> Notifications -> "LinkedIn Notifications Setting". Tapping on this button opens app and redirects to a custom viewController. How it is done?

[image]

I have found documentation about Setting Bundles it seems that this is limited to switches, input fields etc. No deep linking options there:(

How is this achieved? Any limitations to system versions etc?

Comment: You can only navigate to the Settings app `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)` or create your own view controller that looks like the Settings views to manipulate yours preferences.

Comment: @iUrii Thanks for your reply. I'm thinking about "other way solution": from system settings to my app. I have updated my post with LinkedIn notifications settings screenshot. Only some apps have this option in settings. I can confirm LinkedIn and Trello

Comment: @Monet_z_Polski Even i want to show such button in the bottom, even after using providesAppNotificationSettings still can't see that button. Did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must include `.providesAppNotificationSettings` as one of the options when requesting notifications permission.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound, .providesAppNotificationSettings]) { ... }
```

Then, make sure your app delegate conforms to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and implement `userNotificationCenter(_:openSettingsFor:)`. Present your custom VC in that method.

[`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate)

[Another useful article on new (iOS 12+) notification stuff](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/09/preparing-your-app-for-ios-12-notifications/)

Comment: @Monet_z_Polski is this solved your problem, i can't get that button in the bottom.

Comment: @ArshadShaik Yes it fixed my problem. But keep in mind that this code has to be run to enable such option in the settings. Just installing the app will not show the notification settings option. Keeping it behind the notification permission check could also be the reason for you not seeing it.